# New ios7 update & xcode 5 no device found

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I just updated my iPhone4s to ios7 and xcode to 5.
I am trying to run my app on the iphone which worked for 6.1.x and 4.xx. However,
after the update xcode claims not to find my connected iphone testing my app.

```
Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS    device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination?
```

Comment: Xcode preference and enter your dev credentials in the accounts bit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Window -> Organizer.
2. Click on device tab.
3. Click on the iOS device on the left side and click the button 'Use for development'.

Answer (score 5):

Check in Organizer if device is used for development or has lost this property on xcode actualization.

Answer (score 1):

check the organizer like Rauru Ferro said.  It might need some time to update the settings in Xcode.  You should see a progress bar loading, after that everything should work fine.